# Create a new double-field based on the existing string-filed

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

There is an SQL query forming a table. It is necessary to form another double-number field based on one of the string fields in the table.

Values of the original string field (BRLOADSTA0):

```
АК-11 НК-82,7
АК-11 НК-82,8
АК-11 НК-82,9
АК-11 НК-82,10
АК-11 НК-82,11
```

Values of the resulting double-field (BRLOADSTA9):

```
82.7
82.8
82.9
82.10
82.11
```

The request which I've create:

```
'to_number(double,replace(split_part(BRLOADSTA0,''-'',3),'','',''.''),''99999.99'') as BRLOADSTA9, '
```

Full snippet:

```
  Table_mo0000: TTable_Dbf53 = (lname : mo0000;
                                sql : 'SELECT GID,IDBR,BRNAME,IDOWNORG,RDADDNUM,RDADDNUM2,BRKM,RDLANE,BRLEN,BRRIWIDTH,BRVDIM,BRUDIM,BRRWAYL,BRRWAYR,BRFULLOK,CLSBRTYP,NMBRTYP,CLSBRMAT,NMBRMAT,BRLIGHT,BRSCHEM,BRDESLOAD,BRLOADSTA0,BRLOADCRA0,BRLOADSTA1,BRLOADCRA1,LIMMASS,'+
                                'LIMMASSCOL,LIMLOAD,LIMLOADCOL,LIMHEIGHT0,LIMWIDTH,LIMDIST,LIMSPEED,LIMHEIGHT1,BROVER,DATETEST,CLSTESTORG,NMTESTORG,DATEVISIT,CLSVISORG,NMVISORG,GRDCUR,GRDFACT,NMBRREG,BLDYEAR,RECYEAR,CAPYEAR,CURYEAR,OKRYEAR,BRREGADV,BROFFADV,BRDMHEIGHT,'+
                                'to_number(double,replace(split_part(BRLOADSTA0,''-'',3),'','',''.''),''99999.99'') as BRLOADSTA9, '+ 
                                'ST_AsText(ST_Transform(geom_tilemill,28405))geom from bdc.most';
                                sql_graph: '';
                                auto_num : 0;c_fields : 54; t_geom : qmGeometryTypePoint; measure : false; km_gps : false;
                                f_fields : ((fName : 'ID';         fLength : 0;   fPrecision : 10; fScale : 0; fType : qmFieldTypeLong),
                                            (fName : 'IDBR';       fLength : 0;   fPrecision : 10; fScale : 0; fType : qmFieldTypeLong),
                                            <...>
                                            (fName : 'BROFFADV';   fLength : 250; fPrecision : 0;  fScale : 0; fType : qmFieldTypeString),
                                            (fName : 'BRDMHEIGHT'; fLength : 0;   fPrecision : 5;  fScale : 2; fType : qmFieldTypeDouble),
                                            (fName : 'BRLOADSTA9'; fLength : 0;   fPrecision : 5;  fScale : 2; fType : qmFieldTypeDouble)));
```

Thanks in advance even for trying to help :)

Comment: The examples say you just need to extract the string starting at offset 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you tell us which datatype on BRLOADSTA0? I tested using those data provided by you. Please see the below sample.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=743793f32d9371f049abe15c3e7f7332)

try:

```sql
SELECT CAST(replace(split_part(BRLOADSTA0,E'\-',3),E\',',E'\.') AS NUMERIC) BRLOADSTA9
```

Or

```sql
SELECT to_number(replace(split_part(BRLOADSTA0,E'\-',3),E'\,',E'\.'),'99999.99') BRLOADSTA9
```

> #### standard_conforming_strings (boolean)
>
> This controls whether ordinary string literals ('...') treat backslashes literally, as specified in the SQL standard. Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.1, the default is on (prior releases defaulted to off). Applications can check this parameter to determine how string literals will be processed. The presence of this parameter can also be taken as an indication that the escape string syntax (E'...') is supported. **Escape string syntax** (Section 4.1.2.2) should be used if an application desires backslashes to be treated as escape characters.

[Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-compatible.html)

try again:

```sql
'to_number(double,replace(split_part(BRLOADSTA0,' + chr(39) + chr(45) + chr(39) + ',3),' + chr(39) + chr(44) + chr(39) + ',' + chr(39) + chr(46) + chr(39) + '),' + chr(39) + '99999.99' + chr(39) + ') as BRLOADSTA9, '
```

Comment: ```(fName : 'BRLOADSTA0'; fLength : 30;  fPrecision : 0;  fScale : 0; fType : qmFieldTypeString),```

Comment: I compile my code correctly, but when I start function with this SQL code, it returns Error with false encoding. And I can't copy it(
Something like "SQL Error: dfais jdlsafjl dksja fkldsjf numeric: " "

Comment: I've already tried

`'to_number(replace(split_part(BRLOADSTA0,''-'',3),'','',''.''), ''99999.99'') as BRLOADSTA9, '`

and 

`'cast(replace(split_part(BRLOADSTA0,''-'',3),'','',''.''), as numeric) as BRLOADSTA9, '`


maybe it's error with types, hz

Comment: Please change escape string syntax. Check the link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=75af4fdcbbb45938a9440aae5f3df4fd

Comment: unfortunately, this syntax is not recognized by the IDE at all.
IDE - CodeGear RAD Studio Delphi 7

Comment: In CodeGear IDE in row `to_number(replace(split_part('ААК-11 НК-82,11',E'\-',3),E'\,',E'\.'),'99999.99')` snippets `\,` , `\.` , `\-` , `99999.99` will be underlined in red

Comment: Can you write one SP to complete populating data from DB instead of IDE?

Comment: unfortunately, no. Select query is part of a function in my program

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8970947/19538002

Comment: SELECT chr(44) AS "Character of CODE(45)",chr(45) AS "Character of CODE(47)",chr(46) AS "Character of CODE(46)";

Comment: alas it didn't help(

Comment: I rewrite in another method.

Comment: thank you for your enthusiasm, bro.
But it also return similar error like `SQL Error: dfais jdlsafjl dksja fkldsjf numeric: "double"` or  `SQL Error: dfais jdlsafjl dksja fkldsjf numeric: ","`

Comment: Ok, and how can I take `82` from `АК-11 НК-82,9` (without comma and digits after it)?